# Operation not permitted error upon app termination

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, llvm

I can see below error in `Xcode` whenever I terminate my app on device.

```
LLVM Profile Error: Failed to write file "default.profraw": Operation not permitted
```

I am not getting why I am getting this?  Can this create any issue within my application?

I tried searching on google and tried those options, but no help.

Below are the other details -:

1) **Xcode version** -: 11.3.1

2) **Device OS Version** -: 13.3.1

3) **Device** -: iPhone XS Max

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47155543/llvm-profile-error-failed-to-write-file-default-profraw-permission-denied)

Comment: @Kamran yeah, code coverage is checked for me in Xcode.

Comment: The error went away after unchecking code coverage option.I don't know if that's is correct way, so adding it as a comment and not an answer.

Comment: I think it is just an Xcode glitch and would go away by checking/unchecking, clear build, restart xcode etc. Glad it got fixed for you.

Comment: @TusharSharma, same here. uncheck code coverage the error went away. xcode 12.5. running on iPhoneX iOS 14.4.2